# Monge Property for the multidimensional assignment problem

Tags: reference-request, convex-optimization, discrete-optimization

I am currently looking into multidimensional assignment problems. I know that for the "classical" two dimensional case i.e. matching two types of objects s.t. a cost function is minimized ("marriage problem") the relaxed problem and the integer problem coincide. By that, I mean that the vertices of the feasible region are all integer. I also know that this is not the case in any dimension $\geq3$.

Now my question is in which cases does the relaxed, multidimensional (i.e. more than two dimensions) assignment problem always have a integer solution. Or even stronger, in which cases are **all** vertices integer? I'm suspecting that might be answered by the Monge property but I'd be grateful for clarifications, hints in other directions and also suggestions for literature.